# Show that $ \Delta( \mathbf{a,b,c}) = - \Delta( \mathbf{a,c,b}), \mathbf{a,b,c}\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to show that, 
$$\Delta(\mathbf{a,b,c}) = -\Delta(\mathbf{a,c,b}), \mathbf{a,b,c}\in\mathbb{R},$$ where $\Delta$ is the determinant function. I.e. $\Delta(\mathbf{a,b,c}) = (\mathbf{a}\times{\mathbf{b}})\cdot \mathbf{c}$. I have to do this without writing out the coordinates but the basic properties of the in- and outproduct. The hint was to look at $\Delta(\mathbf{a,b-c,b-c})$. I know that this is $0$, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have on one hand for any $x,y \in \mathbb R^3$:
\begin{align*}
  \Delta(x,y, y) &= (x \times y) \cdot y = 0 
\end{align*}
(as $x\times y$ is allways orthogonal to $x$ and $y$). On the other hand, for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^3$
\begin{align*}
 0= \Delta(a,b-c,b-c) &= \bigl(a \times (b-c)\bigr) \cdot (b-c)\\
            &= (a \times b - a\times c) \cdot (b-c)\\
            &= (a\times b)\cdot b - (a \times c)\cdot b - (a\times b) \cdot c + (a \times c) \cdot c\\
            &= -(a\times c)\cdot b - (a\times b)\cdot c\\
            &= -\Delta(a,c,b) - \Delta(a,b,c)\\
\iff \Delta(a,b,c) &= -\Delta(a,c,b)\\
\end{align*}